# Percona install failing

Tags: rpm, yum, percona, percona-xtradb-cluster

After installing percona server so many times without issue it seems I've hit a unique one.

```
# yum list installed | grep -i perc
percona-release.noarch               0.1-10                           @percona-release-noarch
```

As you can see I only have the repo installed. When I go to install PXC5.7, I get this:

```
# yum install Percona-XtraDB-Cluster-server-57
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.atlanticmetro.net
 * epel: fedora-epel.mirrors.tds.net
 * extras: mirror.atlanticmetro.net
 * updates: mirror.atlanticmetro.net
percona-release-sources                                                                                                                                                                  | 2.9 kB  00:00:00     
percona-release-sources/7/primary_db                                                                                                                                                     |  82 kB  00:00:00     
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package Percona-XtraDB-Cluster-server-57.x86_64 0:5.7.23-31.31.2.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: Percona-XtraDB-Cluster-client-57 = 5.7.23-31.31.2.el7 for package: Percona-XtraDB-Cluster-server-57-5.7.23-31.31.2.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: Percona-XtraDB-Cluster-shared-57 = 5.7.23-31.31.2.el7 for package: Percona-XtraDB-Cluster-server-57-5.7.23-31.31.2.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: percona-xtrabackup-24 >= 2.4.12 for package: Percona-XtraDB-Cluster-server-57-5.7.23-31.31.2.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl-DBD-MySQL for package: Percona-XtraDB-Cluster-server-57-5.7.23-31.31.2.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: qpress for package: Percona-XtraDB-Cluster-server-57-5.7.23-31.31.2.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package Percona-XtraDB-Cluster-client-57.x86_64 0:5.7.23-31.31.2.el7 will be installed
---> Package Percona-XtraDB-Cluster-shared-57.x86_64 0:5.7.23-31.31.2.el7 will be installed
---> Package percona-xtrabackup-24.x86_64 0:2.4.12-1.el7 will be installed
---> Package perl-DBD-MySQL.x86_64 0:4.023-6.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)(64bit) for package: perl-DBD-MySQL-4.023-6.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit) for package: perl-DBD-MySQL-4.023-6.el7.x86_64
---> Package qpress.x86_64 0:11-1.el7 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package Percona-Server-shared-56.x86_64 0:5.6.42-rel84.2.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: Percona-XtraDB-Cluster-shared-57-5.7.23-31.31.2.el7.x86_64 conflicts Percona-Server-shared-56
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Percona-XtraDB-Cluster-shared-57 conflicts with Percona-Server-shared-56-5.6.42-rel84.2.el7.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Running the suggested commands result in nothing. I've tried installing PXC56 and it works fine. I then `yum remove` those packages and try this again only to get the same exact thing. I've also tried installing the specific package it mentions in conflict with

```
yum install https://repo.percona.com/centos/7/RPMS/x86_64/Percona-Server-shared-56-5.6.42-rel84.2.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

It'll install fine, yum remove works, try to install PXC57, get the same conflict. I've even tried removing this with `rpm -e` and using yum-utils. I've never had this be a problem before.

UPDATE:

I've narrowed it down to `perl-DBD-MySQL` being the problem package.

```
# yum install perl-DBD-MySQL
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.atlanticmetro.net
 * epel: fedora-epel.mirrors.tds.net
 * extras: mirror.atlanticmetro.net
 * updates: mirror.atlanticmetro.net
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package perl-DBD-MySQL.x86_64 0:4.023-6.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)(64bit) for package: perl-DBD-MySQL-4.023-6.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit) for package: perl-DBD-MySQL-4.023-6.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package Percona-Server-shared-56.x86_64 0:5.6.42-rel84.2.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: Percona-XtraDB-Cluster-shared-57-5.7.23-31.31.2.el7.x86_64 conflicts Percona-Server-shared-56
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Percona-XtraDB-Cluster-shared-57 conflicts with Percona-Server-shared-56-5.6.42-rel84.2.el7.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Still don't know how to fix though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

unfortunately, you have run into a known issue here, and you are right it is to do with the perl-DBD-MySQL package

You should be able to remedy this by running this

```
yum install perl-DBD-MySQL
```

After that, install the Percona repo package, and then after that you can install Percona XtraDB Cluster, Percona Server for MySQL

For more information you can find a number of reports at https://jira.percona.com ... hope this works for you!

*Disclosure: I work for Percona*

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly. Unfortunate that it couldn't figure out to grab 57 instead of 56...